# how to customize the pattern of a field in iReport?

Tags: design-patterns, ireport, customization, digit

Hi StackOverflow experts,
   I've darag n' droped a field into the iReport. This field holds the java.lang.BigDecimal expression class data returned by Query of the Report. In the MSSQL DataBase table this field has been defined as money. I've defined the pattern of this field as  #,###0.00 separate the digits by comma from Right to Left order at each 3 digits(eg. 12,332,324.20).But I want the digits to be separated by comma in same order but at 3 digit interval for first time and at 2 digit interval for remaining digits(For eg.1,23,32,324.20). Please, suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any java expression as the value. For instance, you can use this as the value:

```
"Report between " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format($P{startDate}) + " and " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format($P{endDate})
```

but be careful of null pointer exceptions.

$P{xxx} is a parameter to the report.
$F{yyy} is the field/column in the report.

Comment: Thank you MatthieuF for that quick suggestion. But I didn't get your answer well. Could you elaborate it a little please ?

Comment: In the iReport designer, click on the cell (which will have something like ${FIELD_NAME} in it, and replace the ${FIELD_NAME} with the above expression. As I said in the answer, this can be any java expression, so you can define your own format, or anything really. Look at DecimalFormat